# Close vote dialog box disappears when I try to drag a link in

Tags: bug, close-dialog

I left a comment for a user about a reposted question, explaining that editing was preferred, and I came back later to cast a duplicate close vote. When I opened the dialog, though, I could not drag the link from the comment -- the box closed on me as soon as I clicked outside of it:

[image]

I have done this in the past, though maybe not with the revamped dialog box (love the ability to drag it around the screen, by the way!), so this seems to be at best a regression, if not a bug outright.

Comment: Should I make the .gif loop? I thought that would probably be annoying.

Comment: The auto-close-when-clicking-outside is a new behavior for all dialogs, think it was introduced a week ago to solve some reported issues like dialog staying open without ability to close it other than reloading the page. I don't think they can know in advance you're going to drag a link, so this one is just an innocent victim of the change.

Comment: Thanks for that note, @Sha. I wonder if it can be changed just for this box; dragging a dupe link in from a comment someone else has left is a reasonably frequent action for me at least.

Comment: Never done that myself, but wonder how many really doing it.