# Hide close dialog only on left-click mouseup, not mousedown or right-click

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-dialog

This happens quite often:

1. Notice a question in the "related" pane that I have confirmed or know is a duplicate of this question
2. Click on close → duplicate
3. The duplicate is not on the list
4. Right-click on the duplicate in the side bar and select "copy link address"
5. **Right-clicking outside the close dialog has hidden it**
6. **Click on close → duplicate again**
7. Paste the duplicate's link to the input field

To make selecting duplicates from the side bar easier, I suggest that:

- **Right-clicking shouldn't close the dialog** which would remove steps 5-6 and
- Left-clicking should close the dialog **only on mouseup** instead of mousedown because [doing it like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171603/close-vote-dialog-box-disappears-when-i-try-to-drag-a-link-in) would be even more convenient.

Comment: Why not copy the link before opening the close dialog? Though I'm pretty sure there's a feature request like that already.

Comment: Because the question is just as often as not in the suggested duplicates list, and because I never remember to do that before the dialog is already open.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this a lot of times too. Now, I have started to hover over the related content link. It displays the link in status-bar(in Opera) and as a small pop-up status bar(in Chrome).

Manually typing the question code(number) is tiring and not worth it, but it is a walk-around method.

#### ITT

> I would also like not to have my pop-up box closed and/or the related links should be listed  under the duplicates.