# Modals are lost when attempting to copy text from the page

Tags: feature-request, popups

When flagging for moderator attention using the "other" selection, I have a habit of *clicking* elsewhere on the page. Copying usernames, UID's, post links, the part of the post I'm interested in, etc. etc.

However, annoyingly, clicking elsewhere on the page dismisses the popup. If the popup restored my long, detailed moderator message when opening for a second time, that'd be well and good..... but it doesn't.

**This behaviour is not just restricted to the flagging popup; it's *all* modals on the site (see [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177163/flagging-screen-is-dismissed-when-attempting-to-copy-text-from-the-page?noredirect=1#comment532772_177163) [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177163/flagging-screen-is-dismissed-when-attempting-to-copy-text-from-the-page?noredirect=1#comment532883_177163)).**

Is there any chance (any/ all of the below):

1. Clicking *to copy* (i.e. clicking and dragging) does not dismiss the modal window
2. State of the modal dialog will be restored when reopening it.
3. Clicking elsewhere on the page does not dismiss the modal (there's a close button for that).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post, click "flag"
2. Hit "other" and type "We love unicorns, and horses, they're my friends"
3. Interact with the rest of the page
4. Cry as your long detailed moderator flag disappears into the ether.

---

<sup>Chrome, Windows 8</sup>

Comment: Why would anyone love horn-less unicorns?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Why *wouldn't you*, [they're best of all the animals](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEImD_r6D8o)!

Comment: This is the same for all modal dialogs with text inputs, including the ones we use. So, we feel your pain!

Comment: OK, I thought this was a bug in my WebKit nightly. Was driving me nuts when I went to write an annotation, then needed to copy a username and lost everything I'd been documenting. Good to hear it's not just me.

Comment: Closely related: [Close vote dialog box disappears when I try to drag a link in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171603)