# Don't reset the reject dialog upon opening it again aka keep my custom reason safe

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Consider the following flow of events:

1. I review a suggested edit.
2. It's not good and need to be rejected, none of the reasons fits.
3. I choose "custom" radio button and type a long good reason.
4. I go to the "Reject" button and... miss it by few pixels, clicking outside the dialog.
5. The dialog is closed.
6. I go and click "Reject" again just to be greeted with brand new, clean, dialog. My text is lost.
7. Sad face.

Can you please preserve the reject dialog, at least in case I choose custom reason and type some text, or alternatively store the custom text and re-enter it automagically if I choose custom again?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177163/modals-are-lost-when-attempting-to-copy-text-from-the-page

Answer (score 4):

Seems excessive to hold on to this information because the whole menu is dynamically generated. It isn't reset, because it was never saved.

Perhaps you should lower your mouse sensitivity or pre-emptively copy your text :P

**However,** there is one thing that I can think of. When the popup for the review edit is populated, an event is attached to trigger the removal of the popup. Perhaps before triggering the event which closes the popups there could be some sort of logic in there

```
if($('.custom-reason-text:visible').val().length > 0 && confirm("Abandon custom edit rejection message?")){
 $(document).trigger("closePopups");
}
```

Comment: I count on the team to find efficient and simple solution (jQuery `.data()` comes to mind :)) if and when they decide to fulfil my wish. ☺