# Clicking on background page when improving a suggested post results in edits being discarded without warning

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits

Came across a post which had a suggested edit pending. Clicked on edit(1), when asked to approve/reject/improve, I selected improve.

During course of the edit, I accidentally clicked on the background page, only to find that the edit dialog was was closed and all my edits discarded, without asking for confirmation(which happens when you clicked on cancel button)

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171603/152859

Comment: Reproduced, trying to fix

Answer (score 6):

Turned out to be more of a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) than a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Anyway, fixed/implemented in build rev `2014.1.10.1840` on meta and `2014.1.10.1291` on sites.

Comment: great, thanks a bunch!