# Flagging dialog loses information when it loses focus

Tags: bug, flags

When flagging an answer I needed to use the `Other` category and provide a description of the problem. After I wrote most of it, I needed to reference something in the original question and when I scrolled up to the question, the flagging dialog disappeared and everything I entered was forever lost. This may be a rare situation but I wanted it to be reported.

I should mention that I was on SO.

Comment: I repro'ed this, too: just go to any answer, click flag, other, and then scroll up and *click* anywhere on the page. When you scroll back down, the dialog's gone.

Comment: That one annoys me quite often since I frequently flag as "Other".

Comment: Also annoying: when you open up the "close as duplicate" dialog and try to drag a link into it...

Comment: Got that one covered already, @Shog9: [Close vote dialog box disappears when I try to drag a link in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171603)